# How do common admin panel for ecommerce

Tags: c#, database, administration

For ecommerce sites
1. There will be separate database for each site
2. The management panel of each site will be common

How can I do this in c #? I can make that define web.config file connectionstrings for each new site. But this is very hard.

Comment: Creating a web.config file for each site with different values for connection string is hard?  Then you are going to have issues with the rest of your application if you think this is hard

Comment: Thanks for answer. I dont want change web config or aspx source file different ecommerce site.

Comment: If you want to manage by some interface, you will probably create a super admin interface which will be used only by the creators in order to manage accounts(creating from scratch etc.). You can update connection strings via this interface but you should care the security issues a lot.

Comment: Thanks. when I switch to the common management panel, my customers will always use the actual last management panel.     Is there anyway for this purpose?

Comment: If your customers will always view the latest version of your application, you may have some trouble in configuration management & database schema/data syncronization. On the other hand; you can deploy versioned managenement panels and give permission to the accounts to which version they will be viewing.

Comment: are there any books or documents you can offer about this topic?